# Use XSLT to convert HTML to escaped HTML

Tags: xslt, escaping

I have a large HTML page which is stored within an XSLT variable like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="html">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Test page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="section">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Here is some content.</p>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:variable>
```

I want to be able to use XSLT to output the contents of this variable as:

```
  &lt;html&gt;
    &lt;head&gt;
      &lt;title&gt;Test page&lt;/title&gt;
    &lt;/head&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;
      &lt;div class=&quot;section&quot;&gt;
        &lt;h1&gt;Title&lt;/h1&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;Here is some content.&lt;/p&gt;
      &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;/body&gt;
  &lt;/html&gt;
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to structure my XSLT in order to achieve this?

I want to do something like this, but this isn't valid, obviously:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($html,'< >"','&lt; &gt;')" />
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you first explain *why* you would want to escape the HTML code? Sounds to me like a not-so-great idea in the first place. Maybe other options are better for what you want to do.

Comment: *Which XLST version are you using*? If your are limited to XSLT 1.0 you can place those contents in a separate file (may be your input source or another external document) and copy the nodes within a CDATA block. In XSLT 2.0 it's easier because you can manipulate variable contents as nodesets.

Comment: Tomalak, I am supplying HTML to an XML web service and the rules of the web service dictate that the HTML must be escaped.

Comment: helderdarocha: I am using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Evan Lenz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98316/evan-lenz) stylesheet [**xml-to-string.xsl**](http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/xml-to-string.xsl) will achieve what you want.

The following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="xml-to-string.xsl"/>

    <xsl:variable name="html">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test page</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="section">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                    <p>Here is some content.</p>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="xml-to-string">
            <xsl:with-param name="node-set" 
                           select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='html']/*"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the following output:

```
&lt;html&gt;
            &lt;head&gt;
                &lt;title&gt;Test page&lt;/title&gt;
            &lt;/head&gt;
            &lt;body&gt;
                &lt;div class="section"&gt;
                    &lt;h1&gt;Title&lt;/h1&gt;
                    &lt;p&gt;Here is some content.&lt;/p&gt;
                &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;/body&gt;
        &lt;/html&gt
```

Comment: The XML to string template which you linked to is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have that content in a variable inside your XSLT file, I assume you can change it. In that case you can simply enclose the code inside a *CDATA* section:

```
<xsl:variable name="html"><![CDATA[
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Test page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="section">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <p>Here is some content.</p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
]]></xsl:variable>
```

That will cause the entire block to be treated as a string (instead of being treated as XML and *converted* to its string value). Now you can use it and print it anywhere as a string:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <body>
       <h1>Here is some HTML Code</h1>
       <pre>
           <xsl:value-of select="$html"/>
       </pre>
    </body>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the result of the transformation:

```
<body>
    <h1>Here is some HTML Code</h1>
    <pre>
        &lt;html&gt;
            &lt;head&gt;
                &lt;title&gt;Test page&lt;/title&gt;
            &lt;/head&gt;
            &lt;body&gt;
                &lt;div class="section"&gt;
                    &lt;h1&gt;Title&lt;/h1&gt;
                    &lt;p&gt;Here is some content.&lt;/p&gt;
                &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;/body&gt;
        &lt;/html&gt;
    </pre>
</body>
```

Comment: "*I assume you can change it*" That's some assumption. OP has told nothing about how this variable is populated, so we don't know whether the content is text, a result tree fragment or a node-set.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My variable actually has dynamic XSLT content within it in practice, so Mads Hansen's repsonse is actually my preference, but your solution is useful for people who want to simply output a constant piece of text.